# Prove that a series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (a_n - a_{n+1})$ converges iff the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that a series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (a_n - a_{n+1})$ converges iff the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ converges.

Since $\sum^{k}_{n=1} (a_n - a_{n+1}) = a_1 - a_{k+1}$, the sequence $a_n$ is obviously convergent, but how can I prove it real analytically(formally)?

Comment: What you did is also correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some real $\alpha$
$$\lim_{n\to∞}|a_n|<\alpha$$
$$\implies\lim_{n\to∞}|a_1-a_n|\leq |a_1|+\alpha$$

That is a way how you can present your intuition mathematically